# Need to render as a UMD module - rails-babel-transpiler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, babeljs, umd

I am using rails-babel-transpiler gem mentioned in the official Babel site
[Language API - ruby](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation), for converting es6 code to es5.

The way I am transpiling, below is the erb file

```
<%
require 'babel/transpiler'
transfromed = Babel::Transpiler.transform("import HelloWrapper from '../assets/javascripts/components/HelloWrapper';  ReactDOM.render(<HelloWrapper />, document.getElementById('app'));")

%>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
<%= transfromed["code"].html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

It is getting rendered as

```
//<![CDATA[

'use strict';

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

var _assetsJavascriptsComponentsHelloWrapper = require('../assets/javascripts/components/HelloWrapper');

var _assetsJavascriptsComponentsHelloWrapper2 = _interopRequireDefault(_assetsJavascriptsComponentsHelloWrapper);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(_assetsJavascriptsComponentsHelloWrapper2['default'], null), document.getElementById('app'));

//]]>
```

Can the above code be rendered in UMD way? I have used the plugin "transform-es2015-modules-umd" in babelrc file but it is not getting converted as a UMD module. Help me in figuring this out! Thanks